# Error with T3 Stack(turbo repo - t3-turbo) with Websocket server

Tags: typescript, next.js, websocket, t3

using:

```
t3-turbo
pnpm
```

bare with me please, i'm not a professional. i'm current working on a websocket server for a live messaging feature but i'm stuck at running the websocket server in ./packages/websocket having and error with the module type. i'm just following this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXRRY37MPuk
i did my best to fix this error but i really stuck.

files:

```
// packages/websocket
index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

index.ts, here i initialize the websocket server

```js
import { applyWSSHandler } from "@trpc/server/adapters/ws";
import ws from "ws";

import { appRouter, createTRPCContext } from "@acme/api";

const wss = new ws.Server({
  port: 3001,
});

const handler = applyWSSHandler({
  wss,
  router: appRouter,
  createContext: createTRPCContext,
});

wss.on("connection", () => {
  console.log(`Got a connection ${wss.clients.size}`);
  wss.once("close", () => {
    console.log(`Closed connection ${wss.clients.size}`);
  });
});

console.log(`wss server start at ws://localhost:3001`);

process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
  console.log("Got SIGTERM");
  handler.broadcastReconnectNotification();
  wss.close();
});
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@acme/websocket",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "types": "./index.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --project tsconfig.json --respawn --transpile-only index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@acme/api": "^0.1.0",
    "@trpc/client": "^10.34.0",
    "@trpc/server": "^10.34.0",
    "ws": "^8.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@acme/eslint-config": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.5",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["ES2019", "DOM"],
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["*.ts", "*.mjs"]
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] 02:03:06 Error: require() of ES Module packages\auth\env.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of packages\auth\env.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```